# with open csv SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, file, parsing

```
with open("file.csv" "rt") as file:

  File "<ipython-input-20-911a921>", line 1
    with open("file.csv" "rt") as file:
                                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Any thoughts why it gives me this error. file.csv is on the same directory with my current Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

You need a comma. It separates parameters.

```
with open("file.csv", "rt") as file:
#                   ^
#               right here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("file.csv" "rt") as file:
```

change to

```
with open("file.csv", "rt") as file:
```